# Proper usage of `rescue` (or `try`)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I have a model attribute that may or may not exist and I need to chain some methods after it, I add `present?`. For example:

```
Car.last.passengers.present? and 
  Car.last.passengers.each do { |passenger| puts passenger.name }
```

Would it be better to instead use `rescue` in such cases? For example

```
Car.last.passengers.each { |passenger| puts passenger.name } rescue "No passengers in the car!"
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the responses. I should have asked a more general question, "What is the best way to handle a potentially `nil` result in the middle of a chain of methods?".

Let me make my example more general for clarity. If I call:

```
Car.last.driver.pocket_contents
```

but the last instance of `Car` has no `driver`, I'd be calling `pocket_contents` on `nil`. As per one of the commenters below, should I be using `try`, and if so, could you show me how it would be used succinctly in this case?

Comment: Exception handling is generally usually for unexpected errors. Is this a normal condition, or is it really an exception? If it's normal, then you want to check for `...passengers.present?` and display a message (if you want one) depending upon that condition. If you're trying to keep the code DRY, then consider using a helper method.

Comment: I would argue that `Car#passengers` should return an empty array when there are no passengers in that car. If it did, the whole problem does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to use `rescue` here. Using exception handling mechanisms for flow-control is widely viewed as an abuse of exceptions and generally considered a bad practice.

There is also *probably* no reason to use `x.present? && x.each`, as (if this is an ActiveRecord association) it will *never* return a falsy "non-present" value. It will always return an array-like object representing 0 or more items, which you can safely invoke `each` on. If this is not a ActiveRecord association, you should change your code to follow this convention and return an empty array instead of `nil`.

---

In the general case (assuming [ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) is available), you can use `try`. Assuming `passengers` is a method that may return `nil`, your `.present?` checks should be `try` invocations:

```
Car.last.passengers.try(:each) { ... }
```

This can be chained to artibtrary lengths; both of these are equivalent:

- `a && a.b && a.b.c`
- `a.try(:b).try(:c)`

Note that this will not work if your method isn't returning `nil`, but instead returning a ["blank"](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) value.

---

If `try` is not available, your currently solution is a widely used practice, except that you [should be using `&&` instead of `and`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or) - These are not equivalent operators  in Ruby.

```
Car.last.passengers && Car.last.passengers.each { ... }
```

If you want to save characters, you can use `||` instead of `&&` to supply a default value before you resort to the dirty `rescue` trick you're currently considering:

```
(Car.last.passengers || []).each { ... }
```

---

If this *is* an ActiveRecord association, there are several idiomatic Rails solutions, the best of which is to move your "puts" (which I'm assuming in reality is rendering a series of HTML elements) into its own partial, called `_passenger.html.erb`. Then, you can render the entire collection:

```
= render Car.last.passengers
```

If you want to handle rendering an empty set differently, you should depend on `render`'s behavior of returning `false` when an empty collection is rendered:

```
= render Car.last.passengers || render 'no_cars'
```

This way, your markup for displaying a "There are no passengers" message to the user is stored in a `_no_cars.html.erb` partial and rendered cleanly with a single line.

Comment: Thanks @meagar for a very thorough answer. I believe `try` is what I should be using, as per your answer. The rest of your answer was also very helpful info. I didn't know the difference between `&&` and `and`

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to rescue an exception that should occur.  If it is expected behavior that the attribute may not exist or the object may be nil then you may want to use either the `try` or `try!` methods.

This will try to call the method/attribute if your object is not nil.  The `try` method will quietly evaluate to nil if somewhere along the chain it can not complete.  The `try!` method will raise a `NoMethodError` if you try to call a method that doesn't exist on a non nil object.

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Object/try%21

http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell where the code in your question lives, but I'll assume you are trying to list passenger names in a view. If you make passengers a collection in the controller:

```
@passengers = @car.passengers.all
```

Your _passenger.html.erb partial might read:

```
<%= passenger.name %>
```

You can render the collection in your view pass in a message if the collection is empty:

```
<%= render(@passengers) || "No passengers in the car!" %>
```

More about this here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials